# LTspice: How can I show multiple probes with waveforms using stepping parameters in different colors?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I'm using LTspice IV (4.23I) and I am using the [**`.step`** command](http://www.linear.com/solutions/1831) to vary the capacitance of a capacitor, so that I can see multiple waveforms for a single probe.

If there is only *one* probe, then the stepping values have different colors (see below).

[image: Ltspice single probe different step colors]

My issue is that if I add another probe, the stepped waveform(s) generated from a single probe become the same color. (See blue waveforms below)

[image: Ltspice single probe same step colors]

How can I keep them as different colors, while also keeping multiple plobes on the *same plot?*

Circuit for reference:

[image: ltspice circuit]

Comment: I have given up looking for a solution, I think you can't. Maybe the new XVII has something, but I doubt it.

Comment: I have been using LTSpice almost daily for 4+ years and don't know of any way around this. Just to make sure - you know you can create multiple panes in one plot window, right? If there is one trace per pane, stepped traces will stay different colors. This is what I do to produce a plot with many traces over a stepped parameter.

Comment: @user49628 Yeah I have been putting them in different panes, I was hoping for a trick or hack or something so they can be overlayed on each other.

Comment: I hear you - I have wished for such a hack, too. One other option in your case would be to copy paste the whole circuit so that you have an instance of your model for each parameter you want to "sweep". Then you could name the corresponding nodes something descriptive like Vout_C_10, Vout_C_20, etc. Then, to avoid needing to manually change the colors to match for a given, you can then edit the color sequence for the waveform viewer (in the ctrl panel) so that it is periodic in the number of traces you are working with. Now *that's* a hack... a truly hideous one.

Comment: It is not possible

Comment: Have you tried setting the parameters with the .table command? If you do that, you can vary multiple parameters without having to step multiple parameters. Plotted waveforms will be different colors. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/20925/132649

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there is no possible way to do what the user is asking.

Comment: @laptop2d That doesn't make the question off-topic. It just makes the answer very simple: "you can't". If you think that's correct, write it as an answer.

Comment: @vofa Yes, but it doesn't solve the problem: if you have more than one probe per plotting pane, each probe will be assigned just *one* colour for its own key:value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as mentioned in the comments, there is no way to do this in LTSpice. I recommend plotting the stepped waveform in one plot plane and then plotting the second waveform in a second plot plane. This way you can still see the relationship between the two waveforms while having the stepped waveforms be various colors.